# How to fix this method: java and android app?

Tags: java, android

This its the code methods that im working it verify the app, but on the api 24 doesnt work.

```
   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int i = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(i)) {
                    String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                    File file = new File(uri);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                        Intent intentOne = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                        intent.setData(apkUri);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        activity.startActivity(intentOne);
                    } else {
                        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        install.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        activity.startActivity(install);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So then i got this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:605)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at com.sysvoid.service.Receiver.onReceive(Receiver.java:52)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_55615(LoadedApk.java:1400)
        at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.$m$7(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.app.-$Lambda$aS31cHIhRx41653CMnd4gZqshIQ.run(Unknown Source:39) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

so the method work just to the api 23, but since api 24 doesnt work, it explodes or fails to open. i dont know what to do in this case.

Comment: Most likely is that your activity variable is null. The code that you posted does not cover that part. If you still need help. please post an [mre] or at least all the relevant code.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical problem.